# ERROR: Google Maps API error

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, runtime-error

I have a Drupal server with alias and it doesn't contain Google Maps API key. When I visit A.com it shows Google Maps API warning but no error so gmap is displayed. But when I visit B.com which is an alias of A.com, it shows Google Maps API error and warning so gmap is not displayed. Would like to know how I could remove this error such that the map can be displayed on B.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the unique option is to patch the Drupal module and include the Browser API key in the script tag that loads Maps JavaScript API.

As you can see Google changed the policy on June 22, 2016 and now the API key is required.

http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com.es/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html

Apparently your A.com domain was known prior June 22, 2016, so Google "grandfathered" it and you can use it without key, but B.com domain is the new one and Google didn't "grandfather" it.